# Is the largest eigenvalue a unique weighted sum of the linear combination of the elements of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\lambda$ be the largest eigenvalue of $\boldsymbol{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ ($\boldsymbol{A}$ is hermitian). Is

$$\lambda = \sum_{\boldsymbol{k}\in\mathbb{Z}^{|\textrm{vec}(\boldsymbol{A})|}}w_{\boldsymbol{k}}\prod_{i=1}^{|\boldsymbol{k}|}\textrm{vec}(\boldsymbol{A})_i^{\boldsymbol{k}_i}$$

where $w_{\boldsymbol{k}}\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\textrm{vec}(\boldsymbol{A})$ vectorizes an array? So if the dimensions of two matrices are the same then the weights of the above sum is also the same?

Is there a way to calculate these weights (I know there will be an infinite amount of them, but lets say I am interested in a specific one). Furthermore is $w_{\boldsymbol{k}} \neq 0 ~\forall ~\boldsymbol{k}\in \mathbb{Z}^{|\textrm{vec}(\boldsymbol{A})|}$?

Comment: Since the entries of $A$ are complex, the eigenvalues need not be real. Take $A=iB$ with $B$ Hermitean. Then all eigenvalues are imaginary except, possibly, 0.

Comment: I cannot make heads or tails out of this question. Eigenvalues of complex matrices are complex numbers, there is no largest (maybe you mean largest in absolute value?). Also your formula for $\lambda$ does not even start to make sense. What's vec$(A)$ to begin with?

Comment: My apologies, yes $\boldsymbol{A}$ is Hermitian and $\textrm{vec}()$ vectorizes an array.

Answer (score 1):

There cannot be such a linear dependence of eigenvalues on the coefficients of the matrix. Assume there is such a dependence,
$$
\lambda =\sum_{i,j=1}^n w_{ij}a_{ij}.
$$
First, put all triangular matrices into this formula. As the eigenvalues of a triangular matrix only depend on the diagonal elements, one can prove that $w_{ij}=0$ for all $i,j\ne 1$.

Now, take non-zero matrices with zero diagonal. The formula will predict that the largest eigenvalue is zero, which can be easily drawn into a contradiction.

Comment: You are correct, I was working with exponential elements and only looking at the exponents, so it seemed linear. See the above non-linear sum, do you know of such a result in literature.